# Why there is wrong result for a simple C++ program? Is it caused by #define?

Tags: c++, multiplication

Can I know what is the reason for the output of `t_temp` is `1.47123e+9` rather than `3.1536e+10` (`t`)?

The codes of program is:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#define asd 86400    

int main()
{
    double t, t_temp;    

    t = 31536000000;
    t_temp = 365000 * asd;

    cout << t << endl;
    cout << t_temp << endl;    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `warning: overflow in expression; result is 1471228928 with type
      'int' [-Winteger-overflow]`

Comment: integers use integer arithmetics. Whether you assign the result of that to a double doesnt really matter

Comment: your int is 32-bit long, your calculation results in a number larger than 2^32.

Comment: ... or more correct: it does matter because you might loose precision when assigning an `int` to a `double`, but doesnt seem to be the problem here

Comment: Thanks mates. Very useful comments. I tried to modify '#define asd 86400' into '#define asd 86400.0' or 't_temp = 365000 * asd;' into 't_temp = 365000.0 * asd;' or do them together, the trouble has been solved. I did not realize that the type was defined as 'int' without any code.

Answer (score 1):

When you calculate expression with integer values it casts to int32_t type, and the result is more than 2^32. You need to cast at least one of the operand to higher type.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<numeric>
using namespace std;

#define asd 86400

int main()
{
    cout << std::numeric_limits<int32_t>::max()<<endl;//2147483647
    int16_t Int16Res = 365000 * asd;//Int16Res    int16_t    11264
    int32_t Int32Res = 365000 * asd;//Int32Res    int32_t    1471228928
    int64_t Int64Res1 = 365000 * asd; //Int64Res1    int64_t    1471228928
    int64_t Int64Res2 = uint64_t(365000) * asd; //Int64Res2    int64_t    31536000000

    double t, t_temp;
    t = 31536000000;
    t_temp = 365000.0 * asd;//t_temp    double    31536001024
    cout << t_temp << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's so clear! Thank you very much for your explanation.

Comment: The suggested values are one possible outcome, but Signed Integer Overflow is Undefined Behavior. That means "purple" is technically a valid result. More confusing, ignoring the overflow and producing the proper result is also a valid result, and this does happen in reality when the compiler just stores a 32 bit integer in a 64 bit register and the "undefined" overflow justs spills into the upper 32 bits which logically do not exist

Answer (score 0):

In a sense, YES, this is caused by `#define`.

The following 2 changes also fixes the problem (pick one)

```
const long long asd = 86400;

const double asd = 86400;
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion!